# remove an object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop, arraylist

New to java here and just cannot get my head around arrays. I need to remove an item from an `ArrayList`, I'm lost on how to actually code this. My program reads a `.csv` file, passes from the main class to a second class a string, once in that second class I need to search the array list and remove that string if it is found and returns true saying it was removed. Any help is appreciated.

Second class

```
public class PersonLogImpl {

private boolean remove;
private boolean isLicenseUnique;
private boolean add;
private final ArrayList<Person> person;

public PersonLogImpl() {
    this.person = new ArrayList<>();
}


public ArrayList<Person> getPersonLog(){
    return Person;
}

public boolean add(Person obj){  //add person object to ordered list 
   person.add(obj);

   return add;
}

public boolean remove (String license){ //remove person with specific license from list

    if(person.remove(person.equals(add))){
            remove = true;
    }
   return remove;
}
```

EDIT:
Person Class

```
public class Person{
private String licenseNumber;

public Person(){

}

public Person(String licenseNumber){
    this.licenseNumber = licenseNumber;
}

public String getLicenseNumber(){
    return licenseNumber;
}

public void setLicenseNumber(String licenseNumber){
    this.licenseNumber = licenseNumber;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    int hash = 7;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (this == obj){
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.licenseNumber, other.licenseNumber)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Person{" + "licenseNumber=" + licenseNumber + '}';
}

public boolean validateLicense(){
    boolean retValue = false;
    if ((this.licenseNumber.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{7}$")))
        retValue = true;
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: i think you have problems in your implementation

Comment: for example what's the meaning of `person.equals(add)` ? comparing an `object` with a `boolean` ?

Comment: person.equals(add) is suppose to return true if it is added

Comment: @Newb2Java How is that? Are you using your own implementation of `ArrayList` with the `.equals(Object obj)` method overridden? Please [edit] your question to include the `Person` class.

Comment: No I do not believe so, I am new to all of this so I could be missing bits of code, and thus my problem.

Comment: @Newb2Java you should look at [`ArrayList`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) especially the [`remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) portion. Your `remove(String license)` method could be as simple as `return person.remove(license);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public boolean remove (String license){ //remove person with specific license from list
    Iterator<Person> personIterator = person.iterator();
    boolean remove = false;

    while(personIterator.hasNext(){
        Person personInstance = personIterator.next();  
        if(personInstance.getLicense().equals(license))){
            personIterator.remove();
            remove = true;
            break;
        }
    }

   return remove;
}
```

Comment: This code has syntax errors. Also how do you know that the `Person` class has the method `getLicense(String license)`? OP has not provided the `Person` class in their question.

Comment: sorry was to hasty.. updated the syntax.. btw whatever is the method name to retrieve the and compare the license is.. the algorithm will work.. even if its equals.. I assume the OP is intelligent enough to infer that.

Comment: `person` is of type `ArrayList<Person>`, so we already know it doesn't have a method `getLicense`.

Comment: That is the same question I was asking, I've never used iterator before?

Comment: I see why you used an iterator, since the method is being passed a `String` and not a `Person`, then you have to check for equality of the person's license and remove that person.

Comment: I get an error saying incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Person

Comment: I also changed your if statement to
 if(realtorInstance.getLicenseNumber()){ 
I get error
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: I forgot to add equals.. if(personInstance.getLicense().equals(license))){

Comment: I was able to cast the line that I mentioned above that was giving me the error, is this going to work? Realtor realtorInstance = (Realtor) realtorIterator.next();

Comment: Not sure what is Realtor.. if the iterator was created on a Collection<Realtor> realtorCollection;  Iterator realtorIterator = realtorCollection.iterator().. then YES

Comment: sorry wrong class I copied from, should be Person personInstance = (Person) personIterator.next();

Comment: Better way would be to use generics.. i have updated the answer and this line .. Iterator<Person> personIterator = person.iterator();

Comment: You can simplify the code by using `return true;` instead of `remove = true; break;`. Then, the `return` statement at the end can unconditionally return `false`, removing the need for the `boolean remove` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one yet, create a method `getLicense()` on your `Person` class. That method should return the Person's license and then you can use the `remove` method below;

EDIT: I see now that you have a `getLicenseNumber()` method on your Person class.

```
public boolean remove(String license) {
   for (Person individual : person) { // go through each Person on the ArrayList
       if (individual.getLicenseNumber().equals(license)) // check if that Person's license is equal to the license we're looking for
           return person.remove(individual); // if so, remove that person and return true (remove will return true if the element is found)
   }

   return false; // if we never removed any element we never found a person with that license. In that case, return false
}
```

I'm assuming that each person has an unique license number and that you won't add the same Person twice to the ArrayList (or will stop the user from trying to).
If your wish is to remove any occurrence of a Person with that license, you could use the following method:

```
public boolean remove(String license) {
    int listsize = person.size(); // size before removing any
    for(int i=0; i<person.size(); i++) {
        if (person.get(i).getLicenseNumber().equals(license))
            person.remove(i--); // i-- is required because the list size will change if we remove from it, so we need to decrement i
    }

    return !(listsize == person.size()); // if the size before is equal to the size now, we never removed any and thus return false
}
```

If you want a more simple solution, you could look into the [method removeAll from ArrayList class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: why getLicense() is required as arraylist will contain the value and you just can remove it?

Comment: @Harry the `ArrayList` contains `Person` objects not `String` objects.

Comment: ArrayList is of type Person and not String (if it was, we could just `return person.remove(license);`. We can either look through each Person on the ArrayList comparing the licenses, or create a new Person with that license and directly remove from the ArrayList. But since op didn't post the Person class I can't assume which one would be best.

Comment: Have you tried this code? I'm not certain but I think removing from a `List` while iterating over it will throw an exception (I think a `ConcurrentModificationException` but I'm not sure), since a for-each loop uses iterators in the background.

Comment: yup I just got confused by seeing so many "add" in the op. Well both answers are having similar structure with small variations so either both will be correct or both will be wrong.

Comment: I have tried it and it worked fine. Might be because once we find the Person with that license, we're removing that Person and closing the method right after so it won't go to the next iteration.

Comment: @ViniciusVictor That makes sense, +1.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I haven't tried yet but as its return statement so it will get away.

Comment: This will only remove one instance in the list that matches. What if there are more than one? This is the kind of thing that if added after using the wrong `remove` method, could induce the dreaded `ConcurrentModificationException`. It remains better to use the right idiom, and not depend on an uncommented side effect to prevent trouble in the face of future maintenance.

Comment: I've posted the person class now

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code, I've highlighted them with comments below:

```
public class PersonLogImpl {
    private boolean remove;
    private boolean isLicenseUnique;
    private boolean add;
    private final ArrayList<Person> person;

    public PersonLogImpl() {
        // YOU SHOULD ALSO ASSIGN THE PRIVATE BOOLEANS HERE
        this.person = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getPersonLog() {

        return Person; // What's going on here?
        // You're returning the actual Person class when you should be returning
        // an ArrayList of type Person (I think you meant for the P to be lowercase)
    }

    public boolean add(Person obj){  //add person object to ordered list 
       person.add(obj);

       return add; // You never assign true or false to 'add' (I believe 
       // it defaults to true) so this method will always return true (maybe 
       // false, not sure). you should instead use 'return person.add(obj);'
    }

    public boolean remove (String license){ //remove person with specific license from list

        // The code below makes no sense (no offence).
        if(person.remove(person.equals(add))){
                remove = true;
        }
       return remove;

        // Since I don't know the make up of the 'Person' class I can't 
        // tell you how this method should function. I'll make a guess though:
       for(int i = 0; i < person.size(); ++i) {
           if(person.get(i).getLicenseNumber().equals(license)) {
               return person.remove(i);
           }
       }

       // OR a shorter alternative
       return person.remove(new Person(license));
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added in the bits from the person class that deal with the licence number

Answer (score 0):

@Newb2Java, The `equals` method can compare, in this case `person` with any object, but if the argument (`add` here) is a different type from that of the invoker (`person`), the result is `false`. Though you used a singular noun `person`, its type is plural, a collection of `Person`s. An `ArrayList<Person>` will never equal a `Boolean` (nor a `boolean`). The `List` method `add` will return `true`. `remove` will return `true` if it actually removed the argument, which must be of type `Person`. First, you have to find which element in the list has the indicated attribute value. So you have to iterate through the list, using an iterator being the best way, until you find each instance of an element with the given `License`. Something like this:

```
package practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Personator {
  private final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<Person> getPersons() {
    return new ArrayList<>(persons);
  }

  public boolean add(Person person) {
    return persons.add(person);
  }

  public boolean remove(String license) {
    return remove(new Person(license));
  }

  public boolean remove(Person removal) {
    boolean wasRemoved = false;
    for (ListIterator<Person> iterator = persons.listIterator(persons.size());
       iterator.hasPrevious();
       ) {
      final Person person = iterator.previous();
      if (removal.equals(person)) {
        iterator.remove();
        wasRemoved = true;
      }
    }
    return wasRemoved;
  }
}
```

with this:

```
public class Person {
  private final String license;

  public Person(String license) {
    if (license == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("null license not allowed");
    }
    this.license = license;
  }

  public String getLicense() {
    return license;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person " + getLicense();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getLicense().hashCode();
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object oth) {
    if (this == oth) {
      return true;
    }
    if (! (oth instanceof Person)) {
      return false;
    }
    Person other = (Person) oth;
    return this.getLicense().equals(other.getLicense());
  }
}
```